# Order by letters and characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by

After running my sql query, the result is

```
1.12.1
1.12.2
1.12.3
1.12.4
1.12.5
1.12.6
1.12.7
1.12.8
1.12.9
1.12.10
1.12.11
1.12.2a
```

But I want to this result ("2a" after "2")

```
1.12.1
1.12.2
1.12.2a <-- This one must be here, not at the end of the result set
1.12.3
1.12.4
1.12.5
1.12.6
1.12.7
1.12.8
1.12.9
1.12.10
1.12.11
```

What kind sql query can do this?

Here is my queries... I use SQL Server 2012

> sResultSqlBuilder.Append(" ORDER BY {0} {1}")
>
> If sortExpression = " " Then
>
> sResultSql = String.Format(sResultSql, "Right('0000000000' + FirstNumber,
>   10),Right( '0000000000' + SecondNumber, 10),Right( '0000000000' + ThirdNumbersAndLetter, 10)
>   ", " ")

Comment: What is your source data? What is your current query?

Comment: MySql sort this like you want with normal `ORDER BY`. Which DMBS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Please try, which works in MS-Sql server:

```
SELECT VersionNo, 
Cast(PARSENAME(VersionNo, 3)as int) as Num1, 
cast(PARSENAME(VersionNo, 2) as int) as Num2, 
cast(PARSENAME(VersionNo, 1) as nvarchar(2)) as Num3 
FROM 
(
    select '1.12.2' as VersionNo union
    select '1.12.3' as VersionNo union
    select '1.12.2a' as VersionNo union
    select '1.12.1' as VersionNo union
    select '1.12.4' as VersionNo
)x
Order by Num1, Num2, num3
```